How to overwrite file in docker container?
I have a docker-compose file:
services:
   artemis:
       image: <artemis-image>
       ports:
         - "8161:8161"
         - "61616:61616"
       environment:
         ARTEMIS_USER: artemis
         ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: "artemis"
       volumes:
         - artemis:/app/artemis/brokers

and when I ran docker-compose up then getting error:
Creating ActiveMQ Artemis instance at: /app/artemis/brokers/drpbroker
The file 'drpbroker/etc/login.config' already exists.  Use --force to overwrite.

How to solve it?

ok, I removed this line
- artemis:/app/artemis/brokers

and it's work

Then you're not overwriting any files, or persisting any data
